# jshint command line exclude-path option not working

Tags: javascript, jshint

I created a custom .jshintignore with the following contents:

```
**/*.min.js
**/wp-admin/**
**/wp-includes/**
```

I set the [`--exclude-path`](http://www.jshint.com/docs/cli/) option accordingly:

```
jshint --exclude-path .customjshintignore ./*
```

However, jshint still appears to check all files, even those the should be ignored. I updated to the latest version of jshint with npm (2.5.6).

What am I missing?

Comment: Find any solution to this? I am facing the same issue. A `.jshintignore` in the current directory works, but I'm having trouble with the custom file.